# LibGDX JNIGen (1.7.0) append test to the package

Tags: java, c++, native

Launching (*Run As > Java Application > Foo.java*):

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception {
    NativeCodeGenerator jnigen = new NativeCodeGenerator();
    jnigen.generate("src", "classes", "jni", new String[] {"**/Foo.java"}, null);
    ..
}
```

Got a `FileNotFoundException`:

```
Generating C/C++ for 'src\test\java\bar\Foo.java'...
Command: javah -classpath classes -o jni/test.bar.Foo.h test.bar.Foo
Error: Could not find class file for 'test.bar.Foo'.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Error reading file: jni\test.bar.Foo.h (Absolute)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.jnigen.FileDescriptor.read(FileDescriptor.java:127)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.jnigen.FileDescriptor.readString(FileDescriptor.java:176)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.jnigen.FileDescriptor.readString(FileDescriptor.java:166)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.jnigen.NativeCodeGenerator.generateCppFile(NativeCodeGenerator.java:303)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.jnigen.NativeCodeGenerator.processDirectory(NativeCodeGenerator.java:267)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.jnigen.NativeCodeGenerator.processDirectory(NativeCodeGenerator.java:245)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.jnigen.NativeCodeGenerator.processDirectory(NativeCodeGenerator.java:245)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.jnigen.NativeCodeGenerator.processDirectory(NativeCodeGenerator.java:245)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.jnigen.NativeCodeGenerator.processDirectory(NativeCodeGenerator.java:245)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.jnigen.NativeCodeGenerator.processDirectory(NativeCodeGenerator.java:245)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.jnigen.NativeCodeGenerator.processDirectory(NativeCodeGenerator.java:245)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.jnigen.NativeCodeGenerator.processDirectory(NativeCodeGenerator.java:245)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.jnigen.NativeCodeGenerator.processDirectory(NativeCodeGenerator.java:245)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.jnigen.NativeCodeGenerator.processDirectory(NativeCodeGenerator.java:245)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.jnigen.NativeCodeGenerator.processDirectory(NativeCodeGenerator.java:245)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.jnigen.NativeCodeGenerator.generate(NativeCodeGenerator.java:236)
    at bar.Build.main(Build.java:14)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: jni\test.bar.Foo.h (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.jnigen.FileDescriptor.read(FileDescriptor.java:123)
    ... 16 more
```

Problem, [JNIgen](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.badlogicgames.gdx/gdx-jnigen/1.7.0) is appending `test` to my package name `bar`. So instead of `bar`, jnigen is looking for `test.bar`. But:

1. My classpath (Eclipse) point to `acme/src/test/resources`
2. Maven build my project (others classes) without any problems

Any idea? Using Java 7u80

Answer (score 0):

For those facing the same compilation issue, fixed as below.
Still, executing `Foo` will produce the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Foo.add(II)I
    at Foo.add(Native Method)
    at Foo.main(Foo.java:14)
```

Using then `static { System.load(filename); }` or `static { System.loadLibrary(libname); }` won't fix the problem.
And reading it from as with `Foo` neither.
Any help would be appreciated. Opened this [bug](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/issues/3490)

[image]

```
package bar;

import com.badlogic.gdx.jnigen.AntScriptGenerator;
import com.badlogic.gdx.jnigen.BuildConfig;
import com.badlogic.gdx.jnigen.BuildExecutor;
import com.badlogic.gdx.jnigen.BuildTarget;
import com.badlogic.gdx.jnigen.BuildTarget.TargetOs;
import com.badlogic.gdx.jnigen.NativeCodeGenerator;

public class Build {

    public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception {
        NativeCodeGenerator jnigen = new NativeCodeGenerator();
        jnigen.generate("src\\test\\java", "test-classes", "jni", new String[] {"**/bar.Foo.java"}, null);
        BuildTarget win64 = BuildTarget.newDefaultTarget(TargetOs.Windows, true);
        new AntScriptGenerator().generate(new BuildConfig("foo"), win64);
        ..
    }
}

package bar;

import com.badlogic.gdx.jnigen.JniGenSharedLibraryLoader;

public class Foo {
    // @off

    static public native int add (int a, int b); /*
        return a + b;
    */

    public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception {
        //load foo64.dll from libs/foo-natives.jar
        new JniGenSharedLibraryLoader().load("foo"); 
        System.out.println(add(1, 2));
    }
}
```

MinGW 32 bit and MinGW 64 bit must both be installed (even if I'm on x64) and their bin directory must be in the PATH env. var.
See [JNIGen](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/jnigen) site for more info.